# Problem uploading a file to Ubuntu One using the web interface

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

When I try to upload a file via the Ubuntu One web interface, the server constantly goes down, and it's impossible upload a tiny file.

Any suggestion as to what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

We had some server problems yesterday, and some accounts where affected.
Please try again.